# Qual a melhor forma de declarar um array vazio?

Tags: c#, array, .net, estilo-de-codificação

Em C#, eu posso instanciar um *array* vazio com:

```
int[] array = new int[] {};
```

E também:

```
int[] array = Array.Empty<int>();
```

No entanto, ao fazer da primeira forma, o compilador me sugere usar a segunda, com `Array.Empty()`. Qual a diferença entre eles? Por que devo usar o de baixo e não o de cima?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O compilador sugere? Não sabia que era função dele fazer isto. O meu não faz isso. Não seria o Visual Studio ou algo assim?

Importante notar que o *array* vazio em si tem pouca utilidade. É só para não dar um erro *null*, para indicar que tem o objeto e mais nada. Lembre-se que o *array* não pode ter elementos adicionados nele. Para mudar o conteúdo terá que criar outro *array*, mesmo que coloque ele na mesma variável (referenciando).

O segundo garante que usará a mesma instância e não precisará criar um objeto novo. Já que esse objeto na prática é imutável não tem porque criar vários, se usar em lugares diferentes. Então o segundo é mais eficiente em tempo de execução e consumo de memória. Ali funciona como um Singleton.

[Veja o fonte](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs,947).